# MDX function DrilldownLevelTop - Top 3 Category from Top 3 Department from top 1 Family

Tags: mdx

I trying to get **Top 3 Product Category** from **Top 3 Product Department** from **Top 1 Product Family**, in the schema **Sales**, using the mdx function DrillDownLevelTop.
The 3 levels from same hierarchy.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Unit Sales]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
DrilldownLevelTop
(
    DrilldownLevelTop
    (   
        TopCount
        (
            [Product].[Products].[Product Family].members,
            1, [Measures].[Unit Sales]
        ),
        3, , [Measures].[Unit Sales]
    ),
    3, , [Measures].[Unit Sales]
)
ON ROWS 
FROM [Sales]
```

The result is the follow:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FnCz.png

I get the correct result, but with duplicateds cells. Take attention to values 'Produce, Snack Foods and Frozen Foods'. I am using the correct function, or should I use another?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the 3rd parameter: Level_Expression.

Here is the correct query:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Unit Sales]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
DrilldownLevelTop
(
    DrilldownLevelTop
    (   
        TopCount
        (
            [Product].[Products].[Product Family].members,
            1, [Measures].[Unit Sales]
        ),
        3, [Product].[Products].[Product Family], [Measures].[Unit Sales]
    ),
    3, [Product].[Products].[Product Department], [Measures].[Unit Sales]
)
ON ROWS 
FROM [Sales]
```